# Select where another table is equal to

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `queue` table and a `photos` table, I need to join both of those via the pid(photo id) and then return them if the setting is equal process='1'.

Here is my current command

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM queue 
    JOIN link ON queue.pid = link.id 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

...and this returns the photos and queue table combined fine. But my problem is the IF settings process ='1'

Process Table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `process` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `settings`
--

INSERT INTO `settings` (`process`) VALUES
(1);
```

Any help?

Comment: You've shown us the schema of your `settings` table. What about your other tables?

Comment: what is the relationship between settings and the other tables?

Comment: They are completely different tables, there is no relationship at all. I simply need to check the first row in process and see if it is 1 or 0.

Comment: Tony: If you don't understand my question, don't worry. I already got someone who understood to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *      
  FROM queue      JOIN link 
    ON queue.pid = link.id  
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM settings WHERE process = 1)
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: If OP wants to only return if that exists in the table, I guess this is it.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Some people need to calm down, I can't accept an answer for 2 hours after posting the original question.